# Achievements icon in top bar briefly badged with "0" after closing inbox

Tags: bug, reputation, top-bar, achievements-dialog

When there are (positive) changes in your reputation, this is reflected by the "+x" in a green badge on the trophy icon. When you open the achievements dialog and click somewhere else to dismiss it, the "+x" *briefly* changes to "0" before disappearing altogether. It used to just disappear immediately, but since a few days or weeks I'm seeing that zero (on multiple devices and browsers).

[image]

I'm not sure if it always happens; here is a screen capture:

[image]

Comment: Can confirm that, I noticed this as well

Comment: At least it's not "Loading, please wait..." with some animation.