# Reputation and inbox unread-count notification bubbles disappear on stackexchange.com

Tags: bug, design, top-bar, stackexchange.com

In the top bar, this is what I see on any site:

[image: Reputation bubble showing the correct number]

Except on [stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/). When the page loads, it shows the reputation bubble for a split second, then the number changes to 0, and then it disappears completely. Here it is in action:

[image: Reputation bubble disappearing on stackexchange.com]

This also occurs with the inbox notification bubble / count indicator.

I tested this on the latest versions of Chrome and Firefox for Windows with extensions and userscripts disabled.

Comment: Reproduced in Chrome for Android 109 also.

Comment: That '0' is [another bug I recently reported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/386810/295232).

Comment: @Glorfindel so maybe time to send those two to review?

Comment: lol instead of fixing it, they just make it worse. The unread messages count was fine few hours ago. Wonder what they'll break next, maybe reputation will become 0 on se.com as well, still without anyone from SE noticing they're breaking things.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a race condition with a network request callback and code that needs the result but is run outside the callback body.

I just tried debugging it in my devtools and the race condition is pretty easy to force / reproduce with breakpoints.

```js
// No point in loading unread counts for anonymous users
// plus it helps us with not setting a prov cookie for 404 requests
var unreadCountData =
{
    UnreadInboxCount: 0,
    UnreadRepCount: 0,
    UnreadNonRepCount: 0
};

if (!isAnonymous) {
    $.get("/topbar/get-unread-counts", function (data) {
        if (!data) return; // <- ADD BREAKPOINT HERE

        unreadCountData = data;
    });
}

inbox.handleRealtimeMessage(unreadCountData); // <- ADD BREAKPOINT HERE
achievements.handleRealtimeMessage(unreadCountData);
```

The code looks like it was written expecting `unreadCountData = data;` in the callback to always complete before any calls to `handleRealtimeMessage` functions.

To find that specific code, use the search box, or do a performance trace in your browser with screenshots and at the point where the bug happens, look for the call to `handleRealtimeMessage` in the call-stack flame graph (This is for Chromium browsers. I'm not sure if the instructions are the same for Firefox).

Docs for jQuery `get` (https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) state:

> This is a shorthand Ajax function, which is equivalent to:
>
> ```js
> $.ajax({
>   url: url,
>   data: data,
>   success: success,
>   dataType: dataType
> });
> ```

The rest of the followup (anything that depends on the response data directly or subsequently/transitively) needs to be put in the success callback.